# Laravel 5 broadcast authentication endpoint route not working. JSON returned from webapp was invalid

Tags: laravel, pusher

i'm trying to set up my private channel broadcast via Pusher. I've done all, that [Laravel broadcasting documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting) says. When Pusher is trying to authorize the user - authorization page returns 403 error with HttpException:[image]

I was searching a lot and found one solution, to change the BroadcastServiceProvider this way:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

And now i get 302 redirect to login page and then to main page. Pusher error log now:

```
JSON returned from webapp was invalid, yet status code was 200. [my main page html here, no json at all]
```

- Configuration files are all set, including Echo
- Broadcast service providers are uncommented in config/app.php

I cant find the solution for this problems in simmilart StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Have you turned the debugging on? try setting `APP_DEBUG=false` in your .env

Comment: Yeah, the app is in debug mode and local environment.

Comment: try setting it to false

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to say i even had false+production. No result.

Comment: I've created my own authorization route for now. But i miss Laravel broadcast authorization because of it multi channel easy support.

Comment: I believe the initial `403` response you saw is returned when there's no user object attached to the http request.

Comment: Yeah i know. I saw this 41 line. But i still dont understand how to fix that (

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

change the BROADCAST_DRIVER=log

to

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher